# Uploading AWS serverless application lambda - separately ? ( without ApiGateway settings)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

With a normal Lambda function (in C#) I could publish the Function Handler alone to AWS.

But now I want to :

- Create a serverless application (webapi .Net Core in C#)
- upload it , and only then - attach it to an **existing** ApiGateway

For the demos I've seen, I must update the "Events" section in the `serverless.template` file which is in the solution. ( I might be wrong here).

But

What if I already have a complex ApiGateway which I've built before :

[image]

—And I *only* want to upload the serverless application?

I'm asking because I see that I must declare the ApiGateway also in here :

[image]

**Question:**

Is it possible to only upload the serverless application project ) (without any apigateway info) , and *only then* - attach it to an existing webapi (via aws console) , without also configuring the `serverless.template` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The events portion of the function is optional, so you can leave it out entirely. You can also deploy it without using the serverless transform, by using the `AWS::Lambda::Function` resource type, which may make more sense if you aren't using any of the transforms from SAM.

Comment: can I upload the serverless application ( webapi) to aws lambda with `AWS::Lambda::Function` ? what would be different then? and how can I know what I should change in that file ?

Comment: A serverless application is typically considered a collection of things, like the API gateway with a lambda backing it. You can upload your lambda code using `AWS::Lambda::Function` *OR* `AWS::Serverless::Function`. Some of the arguments change for the former, or aren't available. If you are using any arguments that aren't available you probably need to stick with the latter.

Comment: Thank you Jason. is it possible ONLY to use the already known file from pure lambda function `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? The file that you create and use via the `dotnet lambda` command is the same thing you'd upload when deploying via CloudFormation.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Since I started using serverless application (webapi lambda) i have serverless.template file AND the aws-lambda-tools_default.json file (which i know perfectlly well). All i really want to do is upload my lambda-serverless-api and then (via aws console) bind it to an apigateway. Btw im publishing via visual studio aws toolkit

Comment: You can certainly bind the lambda you deployed via the CLI to an API gateway.

Comment: Jason, is that a SAM file or is it a different one?